# My list with 63 observations becomes a vector with 65 observations after using unlist()

Tags: r, web-scraping

After using `sapply` I have a list with 63 observations, which is the right amount of observations by the way.

After that I want to change the type to a vector, so I use the `unlist()` function. Somehow my vector has 65 observations and I don't really understand why.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url00 = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/dfb-pokal/gesamtspielplan/pokalwettbewerb/DFB/saison_id/2000'

saison00 = read_html(url00)

hi00 = html_nodes(saison00, '.box  .vereinprofil_tooltip') %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% .[seq(1,252,4)] %>% substr(., 2,nchar(.))

hl00 = paste("https://www.transfermarkt.de", hi00, sep = "/")

divh00 = sapply(hl00, function(x){Sys.sleep(9); read_html(x) %>% 
  html_nodes(., '.box .no-border-links.hauptlink') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_subset("liga") })

divh00[sapply(divh00, is_empty)] = "low div"
divh00 = unlist(divh00)
```

From my experience I never got more than the actual amount of observations after unlisting.

Comment: Do you have nested items? With `x <- list(1, list(2,3))` `length(x)` is 2 but `length(unlist(x))` is three.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I thought that I would always get 1 item back from my sapply function, since I thought that "Liga" only would appear once. But I checked again and there is a possibility that I could get 2 items back.

Thank you very much!